# How to create single form to input orders with order table and order_item table that has foreign key from orders table?

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

This is more of a conceptual question on how to format my page and forms for a customer ordering process with the way I structed my tables. To follow normalization standards, I separated order table and order items table, with the order ID as a foreign key in the order items table. The orders table just takes the primary key and has a customer id key, to tie back to the customer. I started with a way to select the customer for the order, and now have to input the product and quantity of the product. The thing is, in the order items table, orderId is a foreign key from the orders table, so an order would need to be created before the item can be referenced to it. The only way I could think of doing it was as I started below, where you select the customer to create an order for, then it gets passed to another page that includes the most recent orderID from the database (as the order was just submitted) and the customer id. Then, on that page, the items and quantities are submitted, tying the new rows in the order items table back to the order table. Is there a better way to do this with just one form where can select the customer, items, and quantity while still following this DB structure?

`

```
       <div class="container">
            <div class="section">

                <h2>Add a new Order</h2>
        <form action="/" method="post" id ="custord">
                <label for="cust">Select a Customer:</label>
                <select id="cust" name="cust">
                 {% for c in cust %}
                 <OPTION value={{c[0]}}>{{c[1]}}</OPTION>
                {% endfor %}
                 </select>
                <input type="submit"><br>
        </form>
```

`

`

```
@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    if request.method == "GET":
      #render list of customers to populate dropdown to start order process
      custlist = selectcust()
      return render_template("index.html", cust=custlist )
    elif request.method == "POST":
      #grab customerid selected to populate order form
      custid = getFormVariable('cust')
      #render new page to input items and quantity for order
          #will send most recent ID from order table and customer ID to page, to tie back to row in order table
      #return render_template()
```

`

[image]
note, employee ID is out of scope for this question as it will be hardcoded (only one employee does ordering)

Answer (score 0):

not full answer but can use lastrowid method from cursor to get the id of the last row inserted into the db